# A more efficient way than: execlp(cmd[0], cmd[0], cmd[1] cmd[2], cmd[3] NULL);

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec

i am trying to make a Command Line Iinterface program that can get line of code from user input and execute them using execlp.

I wanna know if there is a better way of writing my code.

```
execlp(cmd[0], cmd[0], cmd[1] cmd[2], cmd[3] NULL);
perror("Execlp");
```

For example user enter 4 words and each of them will be store in:

```
cmd[0] cmd[1] cmd[2] cmd[3]
```

if we use compile function which is `cc helloworld.c -o helloworld`
this will require 4 space inside array `cmd[]`

or we use `./helloworld`

it will be store in `cmd[0]` and run it, great this works

but i assume what if there is a function which require more than 4 words, will my program be able to execute them? Answer is probably no, E.g.: if theres is 5 or more words , i dont think my program will be able to run it unless in my function it will have 5 element to work

```
execlp(cmd[0], cmd[0], cmd[1] cmd[2], cmd[3]. cmd[4], NULL);
```

or

```
execlp(cmd[0], cmd[0], cmd[1] cmd[2], cmd[3], cmd[4], cmd[5], cmd[6], NULL);
perror("Execlp");
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? by using other function within `exec()` family.

Thanks :)

Comment: why not use `int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[])`?

Comment: Hmm i use this before, but i don't think i really understand them, i will post a code shortly, i tried using them and when i use it it can only accept a number of value i have in argv ...

Comment: `( (char *args[] = {cmd[0], cmd[1], NULL};
  execvp(cmd[0], args);

 perror("Execp"); )`

this code only work with function which require two words, e.g. `cc hw.c`; `rm hw.c`; if i try `cc hw.c -o hw` which is 4 words                               it will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `execvp()`? E.g.:

```
[STEP 110] # cat execvp.c
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* argv[argc] is always NULL */
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
[STEP 111] # gcc -Wall execvp.c
[STEP 112] # ./a.out echo 1
1
[STEP 113] # ./a.out echo 1 2
1 2
[STEP 114] # ./a.out echo 1 2 3
1 2 3
[STEP 115] #
```

Comment: I knew there is a better way then mine, thanks! Solve my curiosity! Can you also explain how this work, and i have tested if there is no int argc inside the function(int argc, char*cmd[])  it will still function as it should be..

Comment: please refer to execvp's man page for details, my English is not as good. for "int argc", it's not an error not to use a function's arg.