# execve() returning error for any command

Tags: c, linux, exec

I have to make a custom shell as a school project and I'm hitting a wall with this:

```
int exec_shell(char **argv) //
{
    if (execve(argv[0], (char **)argv , NULL)==-1) //if an error occurs
    {
            printf("Commande invalide : %s\n", argv[0]);
            fflush(stdout);//vide le buffer
            exit(0);
            return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to be very simple - you put in a command in string form and exec calls the said command.
However, it always returns an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the single warning:

> primitives.c:25:30: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

Comment: What is line 25 of your code?  That's where the warning is coming from.

Comment: The `(char **)` cast is pointless given the `char **argv` argument.  Don't use unnecessary casts.  What's in `argv[0]`?  You're not supposed to pass a null pointer as the environment argument.  Processes are entitled to a minimal environment — and you should pass a valid pointer to an empty list rather than a null pointer (`char *empty[] = { 0 };` and pass `empty` in place of `NULL`). If you checked `errno` (or used `perror()` before calling `printf()`) you would like see `EINVAL` or `Invalid argument` as the error condition.  Also, errors should normally be reported on `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: Please read this specification for execve api. https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve

Comment: Here is an example I wrote using `execvp()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42973015/900078

Comment: Are you sure you are using a  C compiler, somehow this warning smells like C++.

Comment: [RESOLVED] Hey, I would like to thank you all for your answer. It helped me figure out better what was wrong and I found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158782/execve-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step : 1

```
/* myecho.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int j;

   for (j = 0; j < argc; j++)
       printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", j, argv[j]);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compile Program : gcc myecho.c -o myecho

step : 2

```
/* execve.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *newargv[] = { NULL, "hello", "world", NULL };
   char *newenviron[] = { NULL };

   if (argc != 2) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file-to-exec>\n", argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   newargv[0] = argv[1];

   if (execve(argv[1], newargv , newenviron) == -1) //if an error occurs
    {
            printf("Commande invalide : %s\n", argv[0]);
            fflush(stdout);//vide le buffer
            exit(0);
            return -1;
    }
}
```

compile program : gcc execve.c -o execve

step: 3 //Final call

./execve ./myecho

step: observe output.

Comment: You are right. as per your suggestion it modified . thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To pass an empty environment either define and pass

```
char * env[] = { NULL };
```

as third parameter to `execve()` like this

```
execve(argv[0], argv, env)
```

or use a compound literal by doing

```
execve(argv[0], argv, (char*[]){NULL})
```

Also the members of the `exec*()` family of functions ***only*** return on error, so the surrounding code might look like this:

```
int main(void)
{

  ...

  execve(argv[0], argv, (char*[]){NULL});
  perror("execve() failed");

  return EXIT_FAILURE; /* include stdlib.h to have this macro available */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED] Hey, I would like to thank you all for your answer. It helped me figure out better what was wrong and I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158782/execve-no-such-file-or-directory).
The main issue was the path not being correct.